# WSO2 Car file deployment order

Tags: wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

Is there a way where I can specify the order the car files inside carbonapps folder will be deployed?

I have scenario where I have a car file depending on other car.

In this case, I have car that is using the file connector, so the car that contains the file connector must be deployed first.

As I can not guarantee that, we are having some deployment issues.

Is this possible to specify an order for the deployment?

Thanks,

Comment: Can't you create single car with all the dependencies?

Comment: Hi @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne, in this case I can not.

Answer (score 1):

At CApp deployment, the order of artifact types is defined as in https://github.com/wso2/maven-tools/blob/master/org.wso2.maven.capp/src/main/java/org/wso2/maven/capp/utils/CAppArtifactPriorityMapping.java#L30.

And artifacts for each type is deployed in the alphabetical order. By default, dependencies are defined in the artifacts.xml file following the alphabetical order at the CApp creation. 
You can change the order of artifacts deployment by manually editing the dependencies order at artifacts.xml as preferred.

Answer (score 0):

The artifacts will be deployed in the below order. The only way is, you can separate the artifacts into different Composite Applications (move all dependency artifacts into one CAPP) and deploy them in the order as you prefer. But, you have to deploy the dependency CAPP (which contains the dependency artifacts) first.

1. Local entries
2. Endpoints
3. Sequences
4. Message stores
5. Templates
6. Proxy services
7. Tasks
8. Events
9. Message processors
10. APIs
11. Inbound endpoints
12. Other types

Thank you

Comment: Hi, so, we need to deploy the dependency first, right? but when there is a restart, is there a way to specify that the dependency capp to be deployed first? Thanks

Comment: Hi, You can name the dependency Composite Application with a higher alphabetical name. Because the car files are deployed in alphabetical order.